# Reason for WPF Glyphs class existence given that GlyphRun class is available

Tags: c#, wpf, glyphrun

I have been using the `GlyphRun` class to do low-level display of text on a Canvas panel.  I just recently became aware of the `Glyphs` class.  I do not understand the reason for the existence of the Glyphs class, given that the GlyphRun class is already available.

I have not tried using the Glyphs class.  I have not been able to find a non-XAML sample, but that is really not the reason why I haven't tried it.  Even if I did get a Glyphs-based sample working, I don't understand its utility over GlyphRun, based on the very little documentation there is in MSDN.

C#, Windows 7, WPF, any .NET version.

Comment: `Glyphs` is a `FrameworkElement` and can hence be used directly in XAML. From the Remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.glyphs.aspx): *The Glyphs element represents the output of a GlyphRun in XAML*.

Comment: Hey @Clemens, thanks so much.  I do much of my coding in code-behind, my XAML is usually empty (except for styles).  Does that mean I really don't need the `Glyphs` class?  Can it provide me with anything extra in code-behind over `GlyphRun`?

Comment: I guess you could as well use it in code-behind like any other UI element. You might for example add a Glyphs instance to the Children collection of a Panel. That is something you can't do with a GlyphRun.

Comment: @Clemens True, I have been wrapping GlyphRun in my own custom class to achieve exactly what you just described.

Comment: @Clemens The problem is that the MSDN entry for Glyphs is absimal, mostly no help.  It may be more powerful than GlyphRun but the information is obscure.

Comment: That's certainly because there is hardly any reason to actually use GlyphRun or Glyphs at all, if you are not programming at the Visual level. You could just use a TextBlock instead of a Glyphs instance.